# Use one child component from another child component in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-components

I am new in angular

I have 2 child component that module is register in app.component.ts

1)toggle.Module.ts

2)order.Module.ts

**app.component.ts**

```
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { ToggleModule } from '../app/toggle/toggle.module';
import { OrderModule } from "./Order/order.module";
@NgModule({
    imports: [ToggleModule,OrderModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    providers: [AppService]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

there is toogleComponenet.ts and OrderComponenet.ts

I need to access toggleComponent.ts properties in OrderComponenet
can anyone guide me how can I do that?

Thank You

Comment: https://angular.io/tutorial

Answer (score 1):

If ToggleComponenet.ts and OrderComponenet.ts are parent and child, you can communicate through @Input() and @Output() with an event emitter.

Else your probably going to have to make an Angular service.

These are both well documented in the angular docs:

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: if Both are child of appcomponent then ?

Comment: It doesn't matter. If there is any Parent-Child relationship between toggleComponent.ts properties and OrderComponent, then use @Input() and @Output() with an event emitter.
Else I would recommend to use angular services.

Comment: To add to that: emit from child A to parent. Then use the @Input() in child B to bind to the same property of the parent that received the event from child A